# Meshlab Deviation analysis not colored?

Tags: meshlab

I have been trying to find a way to visualise the diffrence between two models I have made. I have imported them into meshlab, aligned them and then used the Hausdorff Distance filter to calculate the diffrences. However, there is no colour map once it is applied. I was wondering if there is more to get the colour gradient to show the diffrences between them or if I am doing something wrong

[image: Mesh after using the Filter]

I have also tried using other filters and sampling such as the distance from reference mesh to see if that would do anything but it I can seem to get a visual representation of it. any advice would be great

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The distances are stored as a quality in the second mesh, which is a float value per each vertex.
To see the distances as colours, select the second mesh and select the option "Edit->Quality Mapper" (or press the button with a rainbow bunny in the toolbar)

[image]

Another way to display the quality as RGB colors is to execute the filter "Colorize by vertex Quality"